# AttributeError: module 'cv2.aruco' has no attribute 'detectMarkers' python

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, opencv, aruco

I'm using python and pycharm on a iMac.

Line of code is:

`corners, _, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(img, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)`

Error msg is:

`AttributeError: module 'cv2.aruco' has no attribute 'detectMarkers'`

I've looked every where and haven't found an answer...

The other "problems" is there are several instances of `cv2.circle(img, (int(x), int(y)), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)`, where there are these carets `^^^^^^` marks underneath the word `circle` in yellow, seems like where all the carets are underneath all the function names(`imread,aruco,arcLength,minAreaRect,boxPoints,polylines,putText`.  The `^^^^^^` are like underscore `_`
but `^` instead)

Any answers to this?? I've tried about every YouTube videos and internet search to resolve this..but am not able to find the answer. I have no/little experience with this. By the way, I'm 75 years old, just trying something new.
Thanks to all for the assistance

Comment: please run `pip list` (or `pip3 list`) on a terminal (not python) and present all lines that contain `opencv`

Comment: I think all packages are install:cv                    1.0.0
cv2studio             1.0.2
ffmpeg-python         0.2.0
future                0.18.3
imutils               0.5.4
numpy                 1.22.3
object-detector       1.9
opencv-contrib-python 4.7.0.72
opencv-python         4.7.0.72
packaging             21.3
Pillow                9.1.0
pip                   23.1.2
pyparsing             3.0.9
pytesseract           0.3.9
setuptools            65.5.0
wheel                 0.40.0
This is everything installed on terminal mode.  formatting in this is terrible.

Answer (score 2):

Do not install multiple packages of OpenCV. They must never be installed concurrently. They will conflict with each other.

Remove all `opencv-*` packages. Then install exactly one.

Choose ***exactly one*** of:

- `opencv-python`
- `opencv-contrib-python`
- `opencv-python-headless`
- `opencv-contrib-python-headless`

Comment: I added just this opencv-contrib-python, and still got errors

Comment: [mre] (code) and complete traceback please. You can edit your question to add that information.

Answer (score 0):

The new version is
corners, ids, _ = cv2.aruco.ArucoDetector.detectMarkers(gray, dictionary, parameters=parameters)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to aruco api changes in opencv version 4.7.0. The below code handles both older and newer opencv versions.

```
import cv2
from packaging import version  # Installed with setuptools, so should already be installed in your env.


if version.parse(cv2.__version__) >= version.parse("4.7.0"):
    dictionary = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_250)
    detectorParams = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()
    detector = cv2.aruco.ArucoDetector(dictionary, detectorParams)
    marker_corners, marker_ids, rejected_candidates = detector.detectMarkers(image)
else:
    dictionary = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_250)
    detectorParams = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    marker_corners, marker_ids, rejected_candidates = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(
        image, dictionary, parameters=detectorParams
    )
```